# Can anyone help me with the marvel api characters per event response?

Tags: api

I'm using the marvel api the get all of the events they have.
I need to get all of the characters of all the events, but I only receive 20.
its says "available: 75" "returned: 20"

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Looks like there are parameters available for "limit" and "offset" to show more results per request or use paginated results respectively. The documentation isn't great so it might take some trial and error

Comment: i could use that to change number of events when i call the events but i cant find out how to change the limits of the characters that come in the events response

Comment: You might need to call the characters endpoint after calling the events. You haven't really provided all the information necessary for us to help you get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
[image: Screenshot event api doc]
Source: https://developer.marvel.com/docs#!/public/getEventsCollection_get_18

You can either raise the limit of the events returned or execute multiple requests to get all the data. I advice you to do multiple requests as this is more future proof (when e.g. the amount of events is higher some other time).

Comment: i could use that to change the limit in the events response but i could not use it to change the limit of the characters that are in every event
(sorry i could not upload a photo here but heres what im talking about)
https://imgur.com/8gH1sRD

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `&limit=100&` between ts and the apikey. For example: `...characters?ts=1&limit=100&apikey=xxx`